# How to capture the mybatis exception "org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException"?

Tags: java, exception, mybatis

Here is the code sample, I want to capture the exception throwed by mybatis:

```
String resource = "com/sureone/server/db/mybatis-config.xml";
Reader reader = null;
try {
    reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
sqlSession = factory.openSession(true);
tUserMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(TUserMapper.class);

if(tUserMapper.insert(user)>0){     <===Exception throwed here for duplicate entry problem 
   return verifyLogin(user.getAccount(),user.getPassword());
}
return null;
```

The exception I want to captured:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'userName' for key 'account_UNIQUE'
```

Comment: You an also check a code complete answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13602807/416369) SO thread. However, in your case since you are using a "org.apache.ibatis..." package thus you will need to catch PersistenceException in place of NestedSQLException since it is the one that will wrap the real cause under it.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the `PersistenceException` as you would do usually :

```
try {
  ...
} catch (PersistenceException pe) {

}
```

But don't forget that this `Exception` wraps the real one:

*From MyBatis code*

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw ExceptionFactory.wrapException("Error committing transaction.  Cause: " + e, e);
}
```

So if you would like the get a grip on the cause of the `PersistenceException` you'll have to use `.getCause()` method on the `PersistenceException`

Be aware that MyBatis can also launch its own `PersistenceException` (`TooManyResultException`,`BindingException` ...) classes, those won't have a *cause* `Exception` wrapped.

Comment: +1 for MyBatis code, you might also want to include example for catching cause of the PersistanceException, for example, cause:  MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the ibatis exception by adding a try/catch block around your statements that invoke myBatis query/insert. For instance, if you use the SqlSessionTemplate and the selectList() method, you can do this:

```
        try {
            myResults = mySqlSessionTemplate.selectList("getInfoList", parameterMap);
        } catch (final org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException ex) {
            logger.error("Problem accessing database");
            throw ex;
        }
```

Whether you re-throw the exception or consume and deal with it here is your choice. However, beware of "eating" it and not dealing with the problem, since this will allow calling code to progress without knowing about the underlying data access problem.